# MediaPlayer making APP not responding

Tags: android, media-player

I have an activity that's using a MediaPlayer to play video content. The activity simulates a TV device by playing different HLS video streams on key up/down presses. After watching some video for a longer time (approx. > 15 mins), when I press any key the APP is not responding and is getting to a Force Close screen. Here's what I'm doing on every key event up/down:

```
    //I'm creating the media player object only once, after every channel switch i do:
    if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
    }

    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(app.channels.get(current_index).streaming_url);
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
        mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //After this I have an onPreparedListener and mMediaPlayer.start()
```

My assumption is that it's eating the device's memory but I can't understand what I'm dowin wrong

Comment: maybe this `mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(app.channels.get(current_index).streaming_url);` line causing problem if you are not using in background thread. because this is an network opetion to get stream data from server so. try  using AsyncTask

Comment: app.channels is an ArrayList, it doesn't make network operations.