# App Hangs/Stops Responding When Loading Video Live Streaming Android

Tags: android, http-live-streaming

I am able to watch videos well when I load the video fast. But when the loading of the video is too long,especially when the internet connection is too slow, it stops responding wherein buttons are not working at all, and pressing back button does not work either. And sometimes, this happens also when I watch the video for a long time e.g. around 25 minutes. I got no message on my Logcat. So what am I supposed to do to avoid this situation? Thank you for your help.

By the way, I am using videoview in playing videos. And the minimum targetVersion of the app is 11. 
Below is my code

```
public class MyClass extends Fragment implements OnCompletionListener,  OnErrorListener{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie, container, false);

        myVideo = (VideoView)view.findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
        myVideo.setOnErrorListener(this);
        myVideo.setOnCompletionListener(this);

        Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                jsonReturn = Helpertool.GetValueFromWeb(parse_the_video_link_with_corresponding_video_id);

                Message msgObj = handler.obtainMessage();
                handler.sendMessage(msgObj);
            }
            @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
            private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonReturn);
                        id_of_video = jsonObject.getString("video_ID");
                        the_url_of_video_file = jsonObject.getString("video_file");

                        PlayVideo(the_url_of_video_file);
                    }   
                    catch (JSONException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
        });
        background.start();

        return view;
    }

    private void PlayVideo(String url) {
        Uri video = Uri.parse(url);
        myVideo.setVideoURI(video);
        myVideo.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                myVideo.start();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            Log.i("TAG", "END");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }   
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        if (what == 100){
            myVideo.stopPlayback();
            PlayVideo(the_url_of_video_file);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I read this but I got no answer. [MediaPlayer making APP not responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749996/mediaplayer-making-app-not-responding)

Comment: Post the code you're using to load your video.  What thread are you on?  If you're doing the transfer on the UI thread or waiting for the transfer on the UI thread (like by an AsyncTask.get()), you'll need to stop doing that.

Comment: @Gabe I already posted my code.